# Unrecognized type error (pyshark capfile ) numba?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

```
import pyshark
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
import re
import sys
from numba import jit

temp_array  = []

cap = np.array(pyshark.FileCapture(sys.argv[1]))
#print(cap._extract_packet_json_from_data(cap[0]))

def parse(capture):
   packet_raw = [i.strip('\r').strip('\t').split(':') for i in str(capture).split('\n')]
   packet_raw = map(lambda num:[num[0].replace('(',''),num[1].strip(')').replace('(','')] 
  if len(num)== 2 else [num[0],':'.join(num[1:])] ,[i for i in packet_raw])
    raw = list(packet_raw)[:-1]
    cols = [i[0] for i in raw]
    vals = [i[1] for i in raw]
    temp_array.append(dict(zip(cols,vals)))
  return dict(zip(cols,vals))

@jit(nopython=True)
def preprocess_dataset(x):
    count = 0
    temp = []
    #p = Pool(5)
    #r = p.map(parse,cap)
    #p.close()
    #p.join()
    #print(r)
    try:
       for i in cap:
          temp.append(parse(i))
          count += 1
    except Exception:
       print("somethin")
    #print(r)
    data = pd.DataFrame(temp)
    print(data)
    data = data[['Packet Length','.... 0101 = Header Length','Protocol','Time to Live','Source Port','Length','Time since previous frame in this TCP stream','Window']]
    data.rename(columns={".... 0101 = Header Length": 'Header Length'})
    filtr = ["".join(re.findall(r'\d.',str(i))) for i in data['Time since previous frame in this TCP stream']]
    data['Time since previous frame in this TCP stream'] = filtr
    print(data.to_csv('data.csv'))

preprocess_dataset(1000000)
```

> 11: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
> cap = np.array(pyshark.FileCapture(sys.argv[1]))
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/root/ddos-detect/shark.py", line 47, in 
> preprocess_dataset(1000000)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
> error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
> raise e.with_traceback(None)
> numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
> Untyped global name 'parse': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>

File "shark.py", line 34:
def preprocess_dataset(x):

for i in cap:
temp.append(parse(i))

Answer (score 0):

**Numba does not support Pandas**. This is explicitly states in the [first page](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/5minguide.html) of the documentation. Additionally, it cannot directly call pure-Python function in `nopython` mode. Thus, you should use `@jit` on `parse` too. Finally, Numba barely supports strings: only basic function are supported and they are not fast. Put is shortly: **Numba is not the right tool here**. Consider using Numpy or maybe Cython. PyPy might help too.

Comment: i tryied to use pypy
but here is :
    from pyshark.tshark.tshark_xml import packet_from_xml_packet, psml_structure_from_xml
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/pypy3.7/site-packages/pyshark/tshark/tshark_xml.py", line 2, in <module>
    import lxml.objectify
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml.objectify'

Comment: See http://packages.pypy.org/ (not sure the page is up to date). Such packages should be supported if you use a recent version of PyPy. It could be a recent issue or the package decided to break the compatibility with PyPy. If so, please fill an issue on the target package. Such problems are not rare though as PyPy is an open-source research project maintained by only few people, this is why I said "*might* help".